# Declaring a variable of type t in a macro in C

Tags: c, types, macros

I need to define a macro in C that does the following.

`swap_m(t,x,y)` interchanges the two arguments `x`, `y` of type `t`.

I'm not really sure how to set `x` and `y` to type `t`. It could be really simple, but I'm new to C and not really sure how to do this.

Comment: *Why* would you write a macro for this? Use a simple function that swaps the values via a temporary variable. Any decent compiler will know what you are doing and generate the most efficient machine code to swap those two values. If you have no serious disadvantages on not getting full score on that task *please* hand in a solution that does not abuse macros for this with a proper explanation.

Comment: `t` is not required for `x` and `y`: they will already have a type. Remember that macros are just a replacement in the code. How would you do the swap _without_ a macro? Once you can answer that, the need for `t` may be clearer.

Comment: Hint : Start to make a swap function for object of type T

Comment: @oldrinb Please note that [the homework tag is now being phased out and must no longer be used](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100).

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
#define SWAP(x, y, t) \
    do {
        t __temp = x;
        x = y;
        y = __temp;
    } while (0)
```

Use as

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
SWAP(a, b, int);
```

Comment: Downvoter: reason? Where is my answer technically incorrect? There should be no other reason for downvote. Or is my answer considered spam? DO REPLY! I can't stand unexplained serial downvoting!

Comment: @oldrinb yes, I saw that too and IMHO it's very unjust. He must be an annoyed kind of person...

Answer (score 0):

You simply pass the type as `t`, e.g. `swap_m(int, x, y)`.

Then you can define a variable of type `t` in your macro:

```
#define swap_m(TYPE, X, Y)    do { TYPE ___tmp = X; X = Y; Y = ___tmp; } while(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exploit memcpy and the sizeof operator:

```
void __swap(void* a, void* b, size_t size)
{
    void* temp= malloc(size);
    memcpy(temp,a,size);
    memcpy(a,b,size);
    memcpy(b,temp,size);
    free(temp);
}

#define swap(a,b) __swap(&a,&b,sizeof(a))
```

Comment: This has huge problems. For example, what if this type is a structure that contains pointers to other structures within itself?

Answer (score 0):

`#define SWAP(a,b) { __typeof__(a) temp; temp = a; a = b; b = temp; }`

Like in: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Ftypeof_operator.htm